# Cannot install 'github-pages'

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, github-pages

I tried installing `github-pages` using `gem`:

```
sudo gem install 'github-pages'
```

However, I get the following error:

> ERROR:  Error installing github-pages:
>       public_suffix requires Ruby version >= 2.0.

But when I checked my ruby version using `ruby --version`, it shows:

```
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
```

So, my understanding is that `gem` is somehow referencing an older version of Ruby(previous was `1.9.3`). How can I fix this problem? My OS is Ubuntu `14.04` and I upgraded ruby using `ruby-install`.

Comment: I have rvm installed. But I used ruby-install to install the latest version.

Comment: `ruby --version` is executed in current user environment, `sudo gem install ...` — in superuser’s one. Try `sudo ruby --version` and you’ll see the glitches.

Comment: sudo ruby --version return 1.9.3. How can I make 2.2.0 the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you do not need to install `github-pages` globally, as you are trying.

Just removing `sudo` in front of your command will do the trick:

```
gem install 'github-pages'
```

Comment: I am getting an error:  You don't have write permissions for the /home/inno/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1 directory.

Comment: You have glitches with your installation (possibly because of previous wrong usage of `sudo`.) The local home directory _must_ be writable. To fix, run from the command line: `sudo chown -R inno /home/inno/.rvm`.

Comment: I am getting: chown: missing operand after ‘inno/home/inno/.rvm’

Comment: There is a space between `inno` (user name) and `/home/inno/.rvm` (directory.)